# Problems adding a new user to OpenLDAP

Tags: openldap

I'm trying to get started with OpenLDAP and I'm following this guide https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/step-step-openldap-server-configuration-centos-7-rhel-7.html

I've done all the steps from a fresh CentOS7 installation. 
I have copy-pasted all commands and have not changed anything. Everything goes well until I want to add a user at page 2 in the guide. The guide tells me to use this command after editing the file `raj.ldif`:

```
ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=ldapadm,dc=itzgeek,dc=local" -f raj.ldif
```

The expected output is:

```
Enter LDAP Password: 
adding new entry "uid=raj,ou=People,dc=itzgeek,dc=local"
$
```

But the actual output is:

```
Enter LDAP Password: 
$
```

I tried entering another password. I also tried using a file that does not exists. Both these yields an error message, so it cannot be any of those. I'm at a loss here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It may be helpful to see the file `raj.ldif` (with sensitive information removed).  Also, maybe the dn already exists and the verb is to `add` instead of `replace`. Check with `slapcat` what's going on in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I redid the whole procedure with three changes:

1. Changed hostname to server.itzgeek.local (Same as they used in the tutorial)
2. Turned off firewall with `systemctl stop firewalld`
3. Turned off SELinux with `setenforce 0`

I'm not sure which of these things that did it, but I do believe it is the hostname that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like slapd believes you omitted any dn in your ldif.

E.g. if you attempted to add an ldif file with this content you could experience the same results:

```
n: uid=raj,ou=People,dc=itzgeek,dc=local
objectClass: top
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
cn: raj
uid: raj
uidNumber: 9999
gidNumber: 100
homeDirectory: /home/raj
loginShell: /bin/bash
gecos: Raj [Admin (at) ITzGeek]
userPassword: {crypt}x
shadowLastChange: 17058
shadowMin: 0
shadowMax: 99999
shadowWarning: 7
```

Comment: Do you mean that I may have missed the first character when copy pasting?

Comment: Could have also missed the first n lines.

Comment: Possibly. Unfortunately, I cannot check if that was the issue, since I have deleted the first virtual machine I used.